# SQLAlchemy: no such table, even if they are actually created

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I started developing a  Flask app with TDD.

The production code as well as the tests are both using the same generic SQLAlchemy instance with SQlite, for the benefits of re usability.

**In __init__.py** :

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

Therefore, both the tests and the real application need to access this db instance, but with a different configurations: tests.py uses a /tmp/ file to create dummy data as it goes.

Hence I take care of calling the right app context everytime I use 'db', regarding the Flask_SQLAlchemy documentation.

Structure:

```
tests.py
run.py
application/
    __init__.py
    config.py
    models.py
    views.py
```

Here is some key code:

**__init.py__** :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

from application.models import *

def create_app(conf_object):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(conf_object)
    db.init_app(app)
    return (app, db)
```

**tests.py** :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from application import create_app
import unittest
import os


app, db = create_app('application.config.TestConf') # Test conf: db file will bt a tempfile
from application.models import Update, Update_State, Device, Confirmation
db.create_all(app=app) # Create tables with app context


class APITestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """Sets up a hardcoded dummy-data database before each test"""

        # Hardcoded fake database

        d1 = Device('1223456789', 'hub', 'R3pTkEAHyUKbUJW7bSK8k5')
        d2 = Device('AZERTY', 'hub', 'R3pTkEAHyUKbUJW7bSK8k5')

        db.session.add(d1)
        db.session.add(d2)

        db.session.commit()

        self.app = app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        """Destroy fake db after each test"""
        os.close(app.config['DB_FD'])
        os.unlink(app.config['DB_FILE'])


    # assert functions

    def test_confirmation_msg_correct(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.get('/confirmation-msg', query_string=dict(deviceid='1223456789', updateid='R3pTkEAHyUKbUJW7bSK8k5'), content_type='html/text')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context(): # Because using using a generic SQLAlchemy() 'db' instance, we need to specify the app. See Flask_sqlalchemy doc, 'Introduction into contexts'
        unittest.main()
```

**models.py** :

```
from application import db
import datetime
import shortuuid

class Device(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    version_id = db.Column(db.String(511))

    def __init__(self, id, type, version_id):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.version_id = version_id
```

There are some other models, but I keep it simple for the explanation.

The problem is in the **setUp(self)** function, where dummy data is added to the database. The engine can't find the tables even though the models are imported and the code is exectuted in the correct app context.

**no such table: device**

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: device [SQL: 'INSERT INTO device (id, type, version_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (('1223456789', 'hub', 'R3pTkEAHyUKbUJW7bSK8k5'), ('AZERTY', 'hub', 'R3pTkEAHyUKbUJW7bSK8k5'))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Moreover, the tables are apparently well created with db.create_all(app=app), when setting **SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True** :

```
2018-07-31 17:06:45,333 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-07-31 17:06:45,333 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2018-07-31 17:06:45,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("update__state")
2018-07-31 17:06:45,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,335 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("device")
2018-07-31 17:06:45,335 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,335 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("confirmation")
2018-07-31 17:06:45,335 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,335 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA table_info("update")
2018-07-31 17:06:45,336 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,336 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE "update" (
    update_id VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL, 
    version VARCHAR(255), 
    description VARCHAR(2047), 
    date_created DATETIME, 
    PRIMARY KEY (update_id)
)


2018-07-31 17:06:45,336 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,349 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2018-07-31 17:06:45,350 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE update__state (
    last_communicated_version_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (last_communicated_version_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(last_communicated_version_id) REFERENCES "update" (update_id)
)


2018-07-31 17:06:45,350 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,368 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2018-07-31 17:06:45,376 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE device (
    id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(255), 
    version_id VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(version_id) REFERENCES "update" (update_id)
)


2018-07-31 17:06:45,377 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2018-07-31 17:06:45,387 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2018-07-31 17:06:45,388 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE confirmation (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    device_id INTEGER, 
    version_id VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL, 
    timestamp DATETIME, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (device_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(device_id) REFERENCES device (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(version_id) REFERENCES "update" (update_id)
)
```

Hope I am clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you think db.createall(app) gets called?

Comment: In tests.py. I removed the create_all() from the __init__.py, and checked it by debugging. Just edited the post

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** :

The application was unable to write to db file created in /tmp by tempfile.mkstemp().
using a relative local path, it works.